# Issue with toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have the following code

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu_head">
<p class="menu_head_open">
<img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="http://oi44.tinypic.com/dyz2r.jpg" alt="">Administration
</p>
</div>
<div class="menu_body" style="display: none;">
    <table class="plan_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="plan_ta_txt" style="width:40%">Moderators</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td style="width:10%">3 </td>
        <td style="width:10%">5 </td>
        <td style="width:10%">10 </td>
        <td style="width:10%;border-right:none;">
        <img style="width:20px; height:17px; padding-left:5px" src="right.gif" alt="right">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="plan_ta_txt">
        Workflow Management<br>(Deparments, Divisions, Teams)
        </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td style="border-right:none;">
        <img style="width:20px; height:17px; padding-left:5px" src="right.gif" alt="right">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- View all and Close all buttons -->
<p style="padding-top:13px;padding-left:180px;">
    <a id="view_but" href="#">
       <img height="31" alt="View All" style="width:87px" src="http://oi40.tinypic.com/30tlytu.jpg">
    </a>
    <a id="close_but" href="#">
        <img height="31" alt="CloseAll" style="width:87px" src="http://oi43.tinypic.com/5yi0bc.jpg">
    </a>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu_head{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ABABAB;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: bold;
   height: 38px;
   padding: 10px 18px 0;
   position: relative;
   background:#e4e4e4 url('http://oi41.tinypic.com/5ofhwg.jpg') center left repeat-x scroll;
}

.menu_head_close{
   background:#e4e4e4 url('http://oi41.tinypic.com/34fifye.jpg') center left repeat-x scroll;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu_head").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('menu_head_close');
        $(this).next().toggle(1000);
    });
    $("#view_but").click(function () {
        $(".menu_body").toggle(1000);
        $(".menu_head").toggleClass("menu_head_close");

    });
    $("#close_but").click(function () {
        $(".menu_body").toggle(1000);
        $(".menu_head").toggleClass("menu_head_close");
    });
});
```

Here I have

1. A tab, if I click on it it will expand and displays a table. I have 8 similar tabs with different tables.
2. I used toggle in order to toggle display as shown in the above code.
3. I have view all and close all buttons, on click I want to display all the tables in all tabs. I used the same toggle to achieve this. and for close all button they must close.
4. since I used toggle they are just toggling. when the table is open and then i click view all the table is closing since I used toggle.

Can any one resolve this problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3Srer/   -   Demo And result of demo :- http://fiddle.jshell.net/3Srer/show/

Comment: Add that demo to your post by clicking "edit" at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use show/hide in order to open or close content instead of toggle, and addClass, removeClass accordingly

```
$("#view_but").click(function(){
    $(".menu_body").show(1000);
    $(".menu_head").addClass("menu_head_close");    

});
$("#close_but").click(function(){
    $(".menu_body").hide(1000);
    $(".menu_head").removeClass("menu_head_close"); 
});
});
```

Comment: Please chain the function calls - it saves a DOM lookup

Answer (score 0):

You can `unbind` the `click event` of `"#view_but"` after it has been toggled, like this

```
$("#view_but").click(function(){
        $(".menu_body").toggle(1000);
        $(".menu_head").toggleClass("menu_head_close"); 
        $("#view_but").unbind('click'); 
    });
```

This is just a fix, I would suggest to use Paulitto's answer.